# Conditional Equation with Sigma

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

sorry if this is common knowledge but I am 17, and we've gotten nowhere near this level at school.

Here's the thing:

I'd like to add 1 to a number each time `a * 1 + b * 2 = x`
. `a` is a number from 0 to `x`, and b has to complete going from 0 to the same `x` before `a` goes on to the next number in that set of numbers.

In python this would be the following:

```
x = 200
number = 0
for a in range(0, x+1):
   for b in range(0, x+1):
      if a * 1 + b * 2 == x:
         number += 1
```

This is a simplified version of the code I wrote that'll find all possible coin combinations for the amount of money in pents you've given as `x`.
This code works, but I'd like to find a formula for this to implement it in a mathematical way, too.

As far as I understand, you need sigma for this.

This is what I've got already, it's probably extremely incorrect because I am probably the dumbest kid you'll meet.
$$\sum_{ a=0 } ^ { x } { \sum_{b=0}^{x} } $$
And here I need 1 to be added to the solution, if and only if `a * 1 + b * 2` is equal to `x`.

Here I only use two loops, but in my code I go from `a` to `h` to find all possible combinations you can make using the following coin options:

1p,2p,5p,10p,20p,50p,100p,200p

In the mathematical case I don't need all the individual combinations only the amount of combinations there are total.

Before anyone asks, yes this is Project Euler #31, but I've already solved it. I'd just like to find a mathematical way to do it and I am not mathematically competent enough to do this without some help.

Also, I don't really know what to tag this as most of these tag names are unknown to me. So feel free to suggest a better tag.

Comment: You solved project Euler # 31 but you want to find a mathematical way. Please explain this further !

Comment: Purely curiosity! To prove I solved it, feel free to give me any number below 500 (to save time) pents that you want the amount of combos for, of course anything but 200. :)